# how to disable an instance of micro-service in spring boot application using eureka server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

i launched this command  3 times in target of my micro-service named **ms-formation** to get 3 instances of my micro-service

```
C:\Users\pc cam\IdeaProjects\ms-formation\target>java -Dserver.port=8083 -jar ms-formation
C:\Users\pc cam\IdeaProjects\ms-formation\target>java -Dserver.port=8084 -jar ms-formation
C:\Users\pc cam\IdeaProjects\ms-formation\target>java -Dserver.port=8085 -jar ms-formation
```

and when i launched eureka server i get 5 instances

```
UP (5) - DESKTOP-ANFEL:ms-formation:8082 , localhost:ms-formation:8085 , DESKTOP-ANFEL:ms-formation:8083 , localhost:ms-formation:8083 , localhost:ms-formation:8084
```

i did not understand why ? and i wanna know how to delete two instances

Answer (score 0):

The other two instances that we cannot infer from where they were spun up based on the information you have in your question are `DESKTOP-ANFEL:ms-formation:8082` and `DESKTOP-ANFEL:ms-formation:8083`.

We can see that those processes are not listening on localhost but on a different network interface. Probably those two instances are already running and were registered with the eureka server just when it is spun up. So you should actually find the processes on that particular network interface (DESKTOP-ANFEL) and kill them. To do this please look at these links (don't want to duplicate them)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48250/find-processes-using-a-network-interface

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165697/how-to-kill-processes-using-a-network-interface

Happy to receive edits and suggestions directly made and will incorporate them into this answer.

Comment: i found just one instance when i re-runed the project